# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException.Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state

Tags: c#

```
public class ConnectionElement : ConfigurationElement
{
     [ConfigurationProperty("uri", DefaultValue = "/")]

     public String Uri
     {
         get
         { return(String)this. Uri; }            
         set
         { this.Uri = value; }
     }
 }
```

It is throwing error stating An unhandled exception of type `System.StackOverflowException`. Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both your getter and your setter are calling themselves. Remember that properties are just groups of methods, effectively. Your class really looks like this, but with a bit of extra metadata:

```
public class ConnectionElement : ConfigurationElement
{
     public string GetUri()
     {
         return (string) GetUri();
     }

     public void SetUri(string value)
     {
         SetUri(value);
     }
}
```

Now can you see why it's failing?

It's not clear why you're casting in the getter, but it looks like an automatically implemented property might do:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("uri", DefaultValue = "/")]
public string Uri { get; set; }
```

EDIT: If, as noted in comments, you're really trying to use the *indexer*, you need to do that instead of calling your property recursively:

```
public class ConnectionElement : ConfigurationElement
{
     [ConfigurationProperty("uri", DefaultValue = "/")]
     public string Uri
     {
         get { return (string) this["uri"]; }
         set { this["uri"] = value; }
     }
}
```

Comment: I think (from memory, a long long time ago) `ConfigurationElements` have some sort of collection of values, all expressed as `object`. The properties are a convenience, so they shouldn't be implemented as auto-properties but instead something like `get { (string) base["uri"]; }`.

Comment: Here we go: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37776/Writing-a-complex-custom-configuration-section

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the getter from within the getter. Likewise for the setter. Just make it an automatically implemented property:

```
public string Uri { get; set; }
```

or define a field and read/write that.

Actually, since this is part of a custom configuration section, you probably need something more like

```
public class ConnectionElement : ConfigurationElement
{
     [ConfigurationProperty("uri", DefaultValue = "/")]
     public String Uri
     {
         get { return (String)this["uri"]; }            
         set { this["uri"] = value; }
     }
 }
```